# Django signal is sending two times

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to use Django signals in my application but the `post_save` signal is sending two times, and the `post_delete` is sending once like it's supposed to.

My signals.py:

```
@receiver([post_save,post_delete], sender=Award)
def print_request(sender, **kwargs):
    print('Request finished!')
```

The result in my terminal when I save an object:

```
Request finished!
Request finished!
```

My CreateView:

```
class ResearcherPrizeCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Award
    form_class = ResearcherPrizeCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('prize_list')
    template_name = 'researcher/award/award_create_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        researcher = Researcher.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id)
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.researcher = researcher
        self.object.save()
        return super(ResearcherPrizeCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My form.py

```
class ResearcherPrizeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Award
        fields = ('title', 'category')

        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class':'form-control',
                'placeholder':'Titulo da Premiação'
        }),
            'category':forms.Select(attrs={
                'class':'form-control',                
        })
    }
```

Comment: where is post_save ? you have pre_save and post_delete.

Comment: sorry, now is correct

Comment: can you show code for saving or creating Award object ?

Comment: off course I can just a second

Comment: Not sure: isn't `form.save` and `self.object.save()` both triggering `post_save`?

Comment: @Adelin No, since `commit=False`

Comment: if I have an update view for this model as well, can it trigger my post_save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is being saved once when you call `self.object.save()`, and again when you call `super().form_valid(form)`.

One option is to redirect in your `form_valid` method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    researcher = Researcher.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id)
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.researcher = researcher
    self.object.save()
    return redirect(self.success_url)
```

Another option is to assign the researcher to the form instance then call `super(...).form_valid()` to save the form and redirect.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    researcher = Researcher.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id)
    form.instance.researcher = researcher
    return super(ResearcherPrizeCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your help